# Tiny_mce image list

Tags: tinymce, imagelist

I was using a very old tiny_mce (tiny_mce_gzip.js) that is no longer working after a php upgrade.  I need to able to use the image selector via the 'external_image_list_url' but trying to find my way round the documentation it only refers to this in v3.  Does it still exist in the latest version?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted!

Easy to find when you know where to look for it.  I was searching the documentation for a phrase in my old version that is no longer used.  "images_upload_url" seems to be the replacement for "external_image_list_url" (although the content of the file pointed to is slightly different).